# iOS CollectionView without cellForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a question, can I use CollectionView without `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, because I will to use collection to align cell item, and click the cell will redirect to different controller, If I use the normal `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and `numberOfItemsInSection`, It can't to Ctrl + right click drag to different controller.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `UICollectionView` you must implement the DataSource protocol and use these methods.

To "redirect" a tap to a new `ViewController` you should implement the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method and then trigger a `performSegueWithIdentifier` within this method.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I added the following code
`- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and 
`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPage1" sender:self];`
, I want the CollectionView Item 1 redirect to collectionView1, and Item 2 redirect to collectionView2,but the collectionView Cell can only create **one segue** to connect to **one ViewController**

Comment: Finally, I understand the concept, Its need to create multi segue from the view controller (not collectionviewcell!!!!!), and named the Segue Identifier like Daniel Said, Thank you Daniel!!